# Cannot run tor as a su on Ubuntu 20.04 with an apache2 server

Tags: onion-services, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to set up a .onion website but I am experiencing some issues in doing so.

I set up a apache2 server and configed the torrc file, but when I save the changes on the torrc file and try to run tor as a su, I got an error that this service is already running but as a different user.

I also tried several times to config and run this with a python3 server and I think this server is running somewhere but don't know where...and I think I messed things up and don't know what to do now..

I have the .onion domain from the hostname but it's not loading when I try to put it in the browser.

Here is the output I receive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sOZZ.jpg

Please help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a tor deb (using something like `apt install tor`), then tor runs as a systemd service and you should not be running tor manually. Run `systemctl status tor@default` to see the service. In addition, you should not run tor as root. The service is set up to run tor as the `debian-tor` user.

Once you've made changes to your torrc file, you can either send a `SIGHUP` signal to the tor process to have it reload the config file, or you can just restart the service with `sudo systemctl restart tor@default`.

Comment: I restarted it but even then I was not able to run tor in my terminal..when I run the apt update command, here is what I get as an output at the end of the update: GPG error: https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Comment: and this: The repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease' is not signed.
how can I delete this repo?

Comment: "not able to run tor in my terminal" what does this mean? And I have no idea what changes you've made to your computer, so I can't help with random error messages. Apt repositories are usually in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: I watched this guy and when he runs tor as a su, the network starts running in his terminal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVMjk9pj2Cw&t=394s

Comment: You should not follow that guide, that is not the standard way to run onion services, and it's less secure. You should not be running tor in your terminal. You should follow a guide by someone who knows how to use Tor, such as https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/d4tpb0/how_do_i_run_a_hidden_service_off_of_a_raspberry/f0ghmmy.

Comment: thanks, man! really appreciate your assistance!